# What is the syntax for create table mytablename.now()?

Tags: mysql

i want to create a table and append NOW() to the end of the table name.
what would be the syntax please?

oops thank you for the correction.

My reason why i wat to do this is i have a script that runs on the database table everyday. If certain conditions are met i delete from the master table. BUT before i delete i just want to make a backup copy by running: create table rc_profile_backup_table_NOW() like rc_profile_table;

then i run: insert rc_profile_table_backup_NOW() select * from rc_profile_table

hope this is better.
thanks

Comment: curious to know the use case of this

Comment: @jimy, It seems a kind of sql injection?

Comment: can't you just do `create table "mytablename.now()"`?

Comment: @DarenThomas It will create table `mytablename.now()` and will not replace `now()` with current time

Comment: I'd think the user wants to have so kind of partitioning for large data sets. You should look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html to partition data.

Comment: The prepared statement will also work for your insert, use some kind of "set @c=concat('insert into rc_profile_table_backup_', date_format(etc...)". Of course, if you run this from a script, it would be much easier to modify the SQL query in your script. For example, with a bash script: now=$(date +%Y_%m_%d); script="create table rc_profile_table_backup_$now etc=";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some rather ugly way to do it, using prepared statements. You might adjust the "now" part, because now makes invalid tables names I think.

```
set @c=concat('create table zogi_',date_format(now(),'%Y_%m_%d'),' (a varchar(10))');
prepare stmt from @c;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt

describe zogi_2012_02_07;
```

It creates a table named zogi_[year]*[month]*[day].

Comment: I see the above is in SQL Server, i use MySQL, how would i do the same in MySQL please?

Comment: No, it was written and tested on a MySQL server 5.1, since your question was tagged "mysql".

Comment: oooh righty...ran it from the command line and it works perfect! thanks i learnt something!